# Why isn't padding or margin working properly in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, padding, margin

I'm trying to create a padding or margin around a component, but when I go to apply it, it causes the app to go off screen. Basically, the top and left padding/margin pushes the right side off screen as if it's doing `padding + width + padding`, instead of working within the set width/height. It doesn't matter if I use margin or padding, the same thing happens with each.

```
export default () => {

  return (
    <div style={{width: 900, height: 600, background: "green", padding: 20}}></div>
  );
}
```

In the picture below, the dark green is the size of the component with padding: 0, and the light green is how it extends if padding: 20.

This is the complete opposite of how I understand padding should work --- the width and height should stay the same, but the interior contents (e.g. text, other components) should have a smaller field to work with.

[image]

It doesn't matter if I do this on the root component or on other, interior components. The same thing happens with each. How can I get the width/height of the component to stay constant while using padding?

Answer (score 0):

This is down to the way CSS works. You create the size and then padding and margin get added on afterwards by default. You can change this behaviour using 'box-sizing'. Try this:

```
const MyElement = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{width: 900, height: 600, background: "green", padding: 20, boxSizing: "border-box"}}></div>
  );
}
```

For more information about box-sizing see this - https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/